# Don't get rep back after taking back your downvote?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I just downvoted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241782/does-code-smell-closed) and then took it back, but I still have -1 rep, when I believe that it used to immediately give you the rep back. Is this a bug or do I have to wait for a rep recalc?

Comment: Are you rep-capped today?  I know it happens at rep-cap.

Comment: but when I remove the downvote shouldn't it go back up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are [over your daily rep cap](http://csharpindepth.com/StackOverflow/ReputationTracker.aspx?so=58088). It's a bit of a bug in the system, but it prevents people from downvoting a bunch of posts early in the day, then reversing the downvote and gaining the rep back over the cap, so the system instead only gives back the 1 point if you're under 200.

If you want it back, you can request a rep recalc, but you may not like what you get (rep losses from deleted questions, etc)

Comment: I thought it lowers the cap? If so shouldn't it raise the cap back up when it was removed?

Comment: I believe it's related to this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2469/why-might-i-lose-2-rep-invisibly

Comment: you can request individual rep calcs?

Comment: @Juan: Yes, moderators can recalculate the rep of individual users

Answer (score 0):

I just downvoted your question and refreshed to confirm I lost 1.

Then I took it back and refreshed again, and I was back to what I had before.

The same thing happened when I tried it on the question you linked.

No-repro here.

Comment: For some reason then it is just happening on my end (using chrome). I just tried it again ad it did the same thing.