# Downvote. Taking back. How does my rep change?

Tags: discussion, reputation, down-votes

I've seen [this question on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12977/dont-get-rep-back-after-taking-back-your-downvote) but it seems old (2009) and does not answer my curiosity. <s>That question refers to Jon Skeets [reputation tracker](http://csharpindepth.com/StackOverflow/ReputationTracker.aspx?so=58088) which does not seem to work now.</s>

My question. I downvoted some posts. About 3 hours later I took it back. I know that a downvote cost one point. I thougt I would get my point back after taking the downvote back. This does not seem to happen. (I can't trace my downvote in my reputation history either).

Can someone explain to me this information (which I don't seem able to locate, have tried). **What is the rules for downvoting and then taking it back?**

Comment: You probably downvoted a question - this [does not cost reputation anymore](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90324/should-downvotes-on-questions-be-free/90927#90927)

Comment: I downvoted a post also. That costed me a point. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908904/cms-system-advice-which-one/8908968#8908968

Comment: So you are saying that downvotes on questions does not cost. But downvotes on posts cost? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes this already cost 1 rep - from quick test I couldn't reproduce your problem though. Downvoted, reloaded - minus 1 rep. Undone the downvote, reloaded - the rep came back to what it was before. do you remember what post you unvoted then undone the downvote three hours later? Or do you have any answer I can test this on?

Comment: I downvoted this qw. Then took my downvote back later. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908891/wordpress-post-thumb-image-use-another-img-on-rolover

Comment: Like I said, downvoting a question cost 0 rep, so you also get 0 rep back. :-)

Comment: Great! Problem solved. If you write this in an answer I will accept it. (Feel free to also downvote mr, "Please write the code for..." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892260).

Comment: Ok. My qw is downvoted. Just wanted to say that, there was (I think) no obvious way of knowing the answer of my question, other than a post in a half year old question with 60 points. (I would personally look for this kind of info in FAQ).

Comment: Just as an aside, the rep tracker still works fine in general... I use it all the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Since May 12<sup>th</sup> 2011](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90324/should-downvotes-on-questions-be-free/90927#90927), question downvotes are free and don't cost any reputation anymore.

So you downvoted a question, it cost you 0 rep, you undone the downvote and got your 0 rep back. :)