# Are you ever tempted just chuck the whole thing and scatter your reputation points to the wind?

Tags: discussion, reputation, addiction

I'm sitting here at my desk sucking up my entire lunch break, thinking this Stack Overflow thing is taking up way too much of my free time.  It's like the [Hotel California](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotel_California#Themes_and_interpretations) - "you can check out any time you like, but you can never leave." I may have to take the afternoon off just to remember what the outdoors is like.

Arrgh!

Comment: What is this "outdoors" you speak of?

Comment: @Bill: It's a magical (likely fictitious) land that is said to exist just beyond these walls. I've heard of some who claimed to have seen it, and even "smelled" it in their own words - as if any other smell but that of this room could exist.

Answer (score 9):

I have been a few times. Also those same times I've been drunk.

Comment: The fact that you don't SO while drunk shows a disdainful lack of commitment to the cause.

Comment: Never rep while drunk!

Comment: BTW what I mean is that I've considered just quitting this whole thing. But those times I haven't been sober :P

Answer (score 5):

I'm trying here... I just can't seem to get rid of this "1" on meta...

hehe

Comment: Aw.  Now I can't upvote you....and you might want to consider changing your gravatar.  Could just be me, but in the small size (as on this answer) it looks like you're out in the woods in the nude.

Comment: Not that there's anything wrong with that.  :-)

Comment: NO UPVOTE FOR YOU!

Comment: Awww...  someone gave me more work to do...  lol

Comment: I wasn't nude but an errant tee shot put me in the woods and by errant it was only like a 10 yd drive... very sad.

Answer (score 4):

My name is Vinko and I'm an addict.

Comment: Hello,           Vinko.

Comment: Hi, Vinko. ----

Answer (score 3):

Once you get to a certain amount of rep, I would like to think it would be hard to get rid of it all. Just think of how many 500 point bounties and spam posts [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) would have to make to get rid of his rep, and there's no guarantee that he wouldn't just make it all back up anyway.

Comment: Yeah, every so often somebody upvotes an old answer of mine.  It's got to be much worse for Jon.

Comment: he's mentioned that there are some days that he's hit the cap limit and he hasn't even written a single answer

Comment: That happened to me once.  I can imagine that it happens rather more frequently for @Jon Skeet.

Answer (score 3):

I am simply just going to link to my response [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11652/how-addicted-to-stackoverflow-are-you/11655#11655)

The summary: I did quit. To Jeff's irritation that is.

<sub>I honestly am not retyping that again</sub>

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 2):

I can completely relate. The only time I spend outside is when I walk from the office to my car, and from my car to my home. I'm thinking I need some sunlight...I'm hopeful that my rep will come in handy when applying for any future positions.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO once you reach 10k, that is usually the point where reputation becomes unimportant. Okay, I am biased as I had my 5 Minutes of Fame during the Beta, but if you look at the Top Users then you can see that the race for the first 5 or 10 positions is going to be incredibly hard. So it's more like "Unlock all features and then have fun and get your questions solved".

Comment: Ditto.  Although I also try to stay on the first 3 pages.

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote a query that uses the data dump to print a summary of how I'm doing on the tag badges. Looks like I'm within a few upvotes of getting C# and Git silver badges! Must answer more questions ...