# Rep addiction recovery button for people over 10k

Tags: feature-request, fun

Related: [stackoverflowers anonymous](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20266/are-you-ever-tempted-just-chuck-the-whole-thing-and-scatter-your-rep-points-to-th)

Given the feel of entrampment some of us feel and considering >10k users are already hooked beyond hope of repair, there should be a button to make every answer/question community wiki for a period of two weeks.

EDIT: Diago actually got a [two week rep vacation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11652/how-addicted-to-stackoverflow-are-you/11655#11655).

EDIT: Sampson, the fastest GreaseMonkey scripter in the west, has already written a [script](http://www.sampsonresume.com/labs/community-waffle.user.js) to help you (and me.)

Comment: If you want a rep vacation, make enough of an ass of yourself to get binned.

Comment: Disclaimer I do not recommend others to go the route I did. It was extreme and I did lose a lot of rep due to the relinking. I do NOT take responsibility for the wrath of the @wood

Answer (score 7):

It already exists...

[image]

Just click...[for two weeks](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V17duGlHEYY).

**Update:** ["Community-Waffle" Greasemonkey Script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20283/greasemonkey-community-waffle-your-posts). Auto-waffle all posts.

Comment: Hey, are those waffles!?

Comment: @Carson: No, it's the Community-Waffle Button. I mean, Wiki.

Comment: Freehand circle + Waffles in a single screenshot.

Comment: @TheTXI: Drop-shadow too..not free hand though.

Comment: You have to force yourself to click for two weeks, a lot harder than a single click

Comment: Now you just need drop-shadows on your free-hand circle...

Comment: Is that a waffle in the bg?

Comment: @Vinko: No need to click, install the "Community-Waffle" Script: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20283/greasemonkey-community-waffle-your-posts

Answer (score 6):

Um...why would you want to turn off your rep gaining ability for a period of time? That sounds more like a "time-out" than a "vacation."

A "vacation" button would be something that just posts random gibberish as an answer and hopefully your gravatar is enough to convince people to keep upvoting you while you're away.

Where's Welbog's markov chain generator?

Comment: Um... Isn't it obvious? It'd be like methadone for SO addicts. You can use it, but you won't get the same high.

Comment: I vote for the vacation button, that'd be hilarious and I'd love to see how much people would be voted up.

Comment: Why would Welbog need a Markov chain generator to post gibberish?

Comment: @Pesto: So that Welbog could take a vacation, silly.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**
I apparently misread the post and have re-read it...  I think that you can achieve the break by simply not logging on.  Since you won't be logging on, there is no need for a button.

I retract my previous statement about reputation distribution as that was obviously not the intent of the OP here.

Comment: You misunderstood.  Vinko has 30k on SO.  He's looking for a button that he can press to turn off reputation gathering for himself...so he could take a break.

Comment: Huh? It is voluntary!

Comment: On SO, lately, I've been largely just logging on and leaving assorted comments.  Doesn't affect my rep at all.

Comment: Also on Meta, I guess.