# Community "Waffle" Your Posts

Tags: discussion, reputation, userscript, waffles

#### Installation

http://www.sampsonresume.com/labs/community-waffle.user.js

#### Description

Following a [recent question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20273/rep-vacation-button-for-people-over-10k), I decided to create a Greasemonkey script that will "Community Waffle" all posts automatically. Essentially, activating this will make you a selfless sharer of information by default, and you will gain no rep for your contributions.

#### Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Haha. Just noticed that this was CW...Forgot I had the script running :)

Comment: One could also argue that you are abusing the CW feature and making things CW that should not be CW

Comment: Can you really "abuse" Wiki? I understand how you can abuse posts, by not making them Wiki. But I don't think it's a two-way deal.

Comment: @TheTXI given that the feature of "having all my questions/answers automatically wiki" has been consistently declined, I think you've hit the nail on the head.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Also, in related news:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/free-waffles

Comment: Oh, man... I **love** waffles! Prepare your logs for **endless 404s**!

Comment: Has the offer expired? Where are my waffles?

Comment: While this broken link may provide some temporary hope, it is better to include a substantive answer and send the broken link to the bit bucket. Answers that are little more than a broken link may be removed.

Answer (score 7):

That's great for answers, but when you post a question as a community wiki you deliberately disallow anyone who contributes an answer any reputation gain from their work.

This may be what you want, but you might consider altering the script so it's easy to force it on just the answers you provide, or both answers and questions.

Answer (score 4):

So we get waffle points?

Comment: I'm not sure about your question, but I suspect the answer is http://gizmodo.com/257153/the-keyboard-waffle-iron

Answer (score 3):

But, how do I get rep then...?  I guess I don't get it.

Comment: smack your head on the keyboard a few times. If you don't get it then, you will have at least made me laugh.

Comment: I just had to explain to my doctor why I have a letter 'H' in my forehead.  Needless to say, I'm gonna need to find a new doctor...

Comment: Or a new keyboard? Where did you get a keyboard with raised letters?

Comment: No, it wasn't the mark of an H.  He had the actual H key embedded in his forehead.

Comment: Ahh...well, either way you wouldn't know which letter it was until you pulled it out, meaning that the doctor would be at least competent enough to remove the key.

Comment: I think it's ridiculous that the doctor had to get involved. Any keyboard weak enough to lose keys after a few solid head-smacks is clearly unfit for production use.

Comment: I see that you've consulted a physician for keyboard-related injuries. You should totally drop that and try jQuery.

Comment: And they call me mad for insisting on steel keyboards.  http://www.cherrycorp.com/english/keyboards/Industrial/J86-4400/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

Could you make your script keep track of all the Rep you miss out on by doing this? That way you can brag about how you "waffled away" 1k worth of points because you're just *sooo* elite. ;)

Comment: Not really, since I can't tell how many total upvotes/downvotes you've received :)

Comment: The script could query the monthly database dump.