# Reputation limit after receiving a downvote before reaching 200 for the day

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

OK, I don't understand the daily reputation limit on SO.

I understand that previous upvotes that didn't count before hitting the limit don't make up for downvotes received after hitting the reputation limit, however I've twice hit this scenario.

I receive a down vote (-2 reputation) before I reach the daily limit, then an upvote that should take me to between 190 and 200 reputation for the day sticks at 190. Only 'accepted answer' reputation seems to be immune.

Is the reputation limit 200 - 10 * number of downvotes? If so this seems a little harsh.

Comment: This has been covered many times before. But see Jeff's comment on this answer - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2360/reputation-limits-and-the-rollover-minutes-concept/37065#37065 - it looks like things might be changing soon

Comment: Don't worry, it's not just you - the rep limit is one of the most mysterious corners of SO.

Comment: Given the likely explanation, it seems that this is likely a duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36362/daily-reputation-limit-bug ; I don't think that I can vote to close on MSO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rep limit is 200 - 2*downvotes - 1*yourdownvotes.

This [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36491/real-reputation-cap/36493#36493) shows how to see where you are for the day.

Comment: I've known how to look at the days summary which confirms just the one downvote, so any idea why I'm sticking at 190? I'd have thought it should be 198?

Comment: @Charles, no, I'd have expected you to be at 198, unless someone removed an upvote, in which case you would have ten less than you had earlier, but no notification of it.  Of course, then I'd think you'd be at 188 (with a 198 max).  If you figure it out let us know, I can't really examine things since I can't see your Today's rep page.

Comment: I think your comment is the most likely explanation, perhaps someone removed an upvote and somehow the system has enabled me to 'make up' the downvote - although I wasn't sure that this was allowed. Accepting your answer as much for the comment as the answer.