# Reputation Math

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, reputation

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Daily reputation cap effectively counts downvotes twice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2241/daily-reputation-cap-effectively-counts-downvotes-twice)
>   [Reputation limit after receiving a downvote before reaching 200 for the day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37084/reputation-limit-after-receiving-a-downvote-before-reaching-200-for-the-day)

So I have 22 up votes today and a casted one down vote which to me means I should have

```
cap(10* numupvotes - numdownvotes) = Cap(10 *22 -1 ) = 200
```

However I have 199 points which would lead me to believe the rep is calculated as

```
cap(numvotes * 10) - numdownvotes = cap(22 *10) - 1 = 199
```

Is this correct or intended.

Comment: I believe this is correct, as to whether it's intended you'll have to wait until (or indeed if) Jeff posts. BTW - this is a duplicate, for example here - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37084/reputation-limit-after-receiving-a-downvote-before-reaching-200-for-the-day